# Knockout and ASP.NET MVC multi page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm pretty new to knockout, and I can't figure out how to best structure knockout with ASP.NET MVC when it comes to applying my bindings and multiple views. I understand how you can do it in a single-page application. But my app consists of multiple server-side controllers and multiple views. And each view can have it's own knockout viewmodel.

When and how should I apply the bindings? I'm loading all my javascript last which means that I can't invoke my viewmodels inline.

Is it a good practice to use a MasterViewModel of some sort and then use the with binding in my views(this is the only solution I can come up with)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each ASP.NET view you create a ViewModel which is bound to the mvc view. I would name the ViewModel after the ASP.NET MVC model.

ASP.NET MVC Model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Knockout ViewModel:

```
var LoginViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.email = ko.observable();
    self.password = ko.observable();
    self.rememberMe = ko.observable();

    self.login = function () {
        ...
    }
};
```

I normally bundle up all the viewmodels .js using ASP.NET bundling and then in each MVC view the Knockout view model would then be bound.

```
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel());
});
```

If you needed to populate the model from the mvc model on first load I would serialise to json using json.net and then pass that into the ViewModel contractor:

```
var loginModel = '@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)';

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel(loginModel));
});
```

Then in your knockout ViewModel you can populate the observables from the model passed into the contractor:

```
var LoginViewModel = function (loginModel) {
    var self = this;

    self.email = ko.observable(loginModel.email);
    self.password = ko.observable(loginModel.password);
    self.rememberMe = ko.observable(loginModel.rememberMe);
```

In order to use camel case for the json I change json.net to serialise to camlecase.

You would use some MasterViewModel as explained by super cool if you having a complex page similar to a SPA such as a form page with multiple steps, essentially a page with multiple view states.

Comment: I can't bind in each MVC view due to the fact that I load all my javascript at the end of the BODY. Otherwise I would do exactly like you proposed.

Comment: Sure you can. Use @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) at the bottom of your body. Then in your views you can use @section scripts { .. } and the scripts will be rendered at the bottom of the body

Comment: Didnt know about @RenderSection. It surprises me what you can miss sometimes! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

yes it is a good practice because if you try to make a single viewmodel for multiple views everything looks complex and readability is lost (purely depends on how complexity).

You have to try something like this to make things readable and simple

**View Model:**

```
var MasterViewModel = {
    vm1 : new ViewModel1(),
    vm2 : new ViewModel2(),
    vm3 : new ViewModel3(),
    vm4 : new ViewModel4(),
}

ko.applyBindings(MasterViewModel);
```

Another possible way which works fine just by adding additional parameter to `ko.applybindings` to differentiate which view belongs to which view model

**Example:**

```
//view
<div id='viewmodel1'>
</div>
<div id='viewmodel2'>
</div>

var vm1 = function(){ //code}
var vm2 = function(){ //code}

ko.applyBindings(new vm1(), document.getElementById("viewmodel1"));
ko.applyBindings(new vm2(), document.getElementById("viewmodel2"));
```

If i recall well enough there are few similar posts in stack-overflow you can refer

Comment: This works great in a single-page application with different sections. But when and how should I apply the bindings? I can't do it inline since I load all my javascript at the end of the BODY. You can bind like that, but you have to nullcheck document.getElementById before binding in order to know if the element exists on the page or not.